# Can't combine CSS Sprite and Background Gradient in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, webkit

This used to work fine, however recently the gradient doesn't work properly in Webkit.  Seems to be fine in Firefox.  Can someone check if I'm setting something incorrectly.  Don't pay attention to the images. Its the gradient I can't get to render. Any ideas please?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/UdxUg/2/

```
-webkit-gradient
```

Comment: Please provide an image of what you want to create so I know what I'm looking at. I'm getting weird results in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's due to the old syntax, generally webkit/blink now allows using a vendor-less value.

Generally you should use a :pseudo-element --> http://jsfiddle.net/UdxUg/6/

anyways here's a code that works.

#### works with image

```
.create {
    border: 1px solid #63ac5c;
    background: #d9ead8 url('http://tinyurl.com/mezxsk6') no-repeat 0px -10px;
    background: url('http://tinyurl.com/mezxsk6') no-repeat 0px -10px, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #dbe8d9), color-stop(100%, #bcd7b9));
    /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */
    background: url('http://tinyurl.com/mezxsk6') no-repeat 0px -10px, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbe8d9, #bcd7b9);
    background: url('http://tinyurl.com/mezxsk6') no-repeat 0px -10px, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbe8d9, #bcd7b9);
    background: url('http://tinyurl.com/mezxsk6') no-repeat 0px -10px, linear-gradient(top, #dbe8d9, #bcd7b9);
    height: 23px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

#### use this instead though

```
.create {
    border: 1px solid #63ac5c;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #dbe8d9), color-stop(100%, #bcd7b9)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dbe8d9, #bcd7b9);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dbe8d9, #bcd7b9);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #dbe8d9, #bcd7b9);

    height: 23px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative
}
    
.create:before {
    content: '';
    background: #d9ead8 url('http://tinyurl.com/mezxsk6') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. However, when was this changed? How come it works fine in Firefox?

Comment: Firefox (gecko already uses the "new syntax"). I think the old syntax is deprecated since a few years now. I know it is needed for iOS4. But desktop-webkit browsers use the new syntax only. The old one works but with quirks. (see the order of the properties - oldest first, last one is without vendor-prefix). the example with the pseudo-element should also work with the old syntax. Like I already said. When using the sprite like that you need a pseudo-element. If you want no pseudo-element the sprite should have icons vertically not horizontally, so only one icon is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check this I always use this generator to generate gradients, it is faster and it is good.

[CSS3 Ultimate Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

BTW if you remove that images the gradient works just fine in webkit.

[Check on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdxUg/4/)

```
.create {
    border: 1px solid #63ac5c;

    background: rgb(188,215,185); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background:     url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(188,215,185,1) 24%, rgba(219,232,217,1) 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(24%,rgba(188,215,185,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(219,232,217,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(188,215,185,1) 24%,rgba(219,232,217,1) 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(188,215,185,1) 24%,rgba(219,232,217,1) 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(188,215,185,1) 24%,rgba(219,232,217,1) 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(188,215,185,1) 24%,rgba(219,232,217,1) 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bcd7b9', endColorstr='#dbe8d9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

    height: 23px;
    text-align:center;
}
```